# AJAX: questions not rendering to the browser

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have been tasked with getting a small quiz application working. I saved my questions as a `json` file and conducting an `http` request. When I initialed ran a `JSON.parse()` of the questions, it rendered to the browser.

```
var output = document.getElementById('output');
// this allows us to keep it as a global value
var myObj = '';
loadQuestions();
console.log(myObj);

// var myQuestions = '[{"question":"What is your nearest star?","answers":{"a":"Alpha Centauri","b":"Barnard\'s Star","c":"Sirius","d":"Sol"},"correctAnswer":"d"},{"question":"What color is grass?","answers":{"a":"Blue","b":"Red","c":"Green","d":"Purple"},"correctAnswer":"c"}]';
// var myObj = JSON.parse(myQuestions);
// for (var i in myObj) {
//   output.innerHTML += myObj[i].question + '? <br>';
// }
```

However, when I refactored it to do an `AJAX` call, it is iterating through the console, but not in the browser window:

```
var output = document.getElementById('output');
// this allows us to keep it as a global value
var myObj = '';
loadQuestions();
console.log(myObj);

function loadQuestions() {
  // http request
  // this will allow you to pull in
  // the questions from the api that
  // your questions or data is stored in
  var a = new XMLHttpRequest();
  a.open("GET", "https://api.myjson.com/bins/8xmud", true); // opened request with address with
  a.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (a.readyState == 1) {
      var myQuestions = JSON.parse(a.responseText);
      console.log(myQuestions);
      for (var i in myQuestions) {
        output.innerHTML = myQuestions[i].question + '? <br>';
      }
    }
    console.log(a);
  }
  a.send();
}
```

I thought it could be my `for...in` loop, but that's written correctly. I am unclear as to why, despite getting a `Status: OK` or `200`, it is not iterating through the browser window as before.

Comment: well readyState of 1 is not when the content is there..... learn about the ready states....

Comment: thanks for the clue @epascarello. The reason I wrote one is because with the old code, I saw the output of 1 in the console and I thought that was the `readyState` integer I needed.

Comment: as @epascarello alluded to, you want to change your `readyState` check to 4 - see documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState

Comment: @epascarello, as soon as I changed it to 4, it now displays one of my questions, not sure why it doesn't display both, but feel free to post your comment as the answer.

Comment: well pretty hard to display both when you replace the html each time in the loop.

Comment: change `output.innerHTML =` to `output.innerHTML +=`

Comment: @Luca, my bad, I did have that before, but in refactoring to solve this bug, I changed it and forgot to put it back to `+=`

Comment: So, @epascarello if you want to post your comment as the answer, I will mark it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var output = document.getElementById('output');
// this allows us to keep it as a global value
var myObj = '';
loadQuestions();
console.log(myObj);

function loadQuestions() {
  // http request
  // this will allow you to pull in
  // the questions from the api that
  // your questions or data is stored in
  var a = new XMLHttpRequest();
  a.open("GET", "https://api.myjson.com/bins/8xmud", true); // opened request with address with
  a.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (a.readyState == 4) {
      var myQuestions = JSON.parse(a.responseText);
      console.log(myQuestions);
      for (var i in myQuestions) {
        output.innerHTML += myQuestions[i].question + '? <br>';
      }
    }
    console.log(a);
  }
  a.send();
}
```

```html
<div id ="output"></div>
```

Comment: @ale please check if it helps.